# Rewrite url using htaccess is not working correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite u a url using htacces, my url es https://example.com/web/xx and y change web for other word example https://example.com/test/xx RewriteRule ^web(.*) test$1 but dont work, any idea?
Here is my .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-1

 RewriteRule ^web(.*) test$1

 RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Is `/web/` a directory or an existing link?

Comment: is a directory, o mean, is a framework and web is the public folder, but i can changed because all the apps is using /web/xxx for ajax etc, so i need write a rule for specific url to send a token, https://example.com/web/abcd123 (token) but to send it like https://example.com/test/abc123

Comment: how does it not work? whet's the error or where are you being redirected? (if anywhere) what is displayed on the screen when you try https://example.com/web/xx ? are the links working withot index.php ?

Comment: the error is page not found, and yes without index.php work fine, example https://example.com/web/login work finde, but https://example.com/test/login dont work, (i am using a framework Yii2) and i know the problem is the document Root but i can change the path to the public folder (web) for this reason i need use a rule on htacces or virtual host